# Direct Sum Of Two Subspace Of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and define the subspaces
>
> $$U=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\ 0&d \end{pmatrix}: a,d\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
>
> $$W=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}: a+c=0\:{\rm and}\:b+d=0\right\}$$
>
> Prove that $V=U\oplus W$

I got everything covered it boil down to finding a matrix $A\in V$ such that $A=U+W$ but I can not find one, it tried be

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -a&-b \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It absolutely does not boil down to finding such a matrix.

Comment: It boils down to showing that there is a basis of $V$ consisting solely of vectors in $U$ and vectors in $W$ and that there are no non-zero vectors belonging to the intersection of $U$ and $W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "everything covered" - what exactly have you done?

Note that an element of $W$ is of the form (using $a+c=0$ and $b+d=0$):
$$\begin{pmatrix} -c &b\\ c& -b \end{pmatrix}$$
So a matrix in $U+W$ has the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a-c &b\\ c& d-b \end{pmatrix}$$
From this it should be clear that:
$$\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}}=\begin{pmatrix} a-c &b\\ c& d-b \end{pmatrix}$$
where the blue matrix is an arbitrary element of $V$, always has a *unique solution* for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: $W$ is not a matrix, but a subspace.

Comment: @eranreches Thanks, I was still editing and adjusted that as well.